# How to display picklist in VF and save selected value?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom object called `Program__c` which has a picklist called `Categories__c`.
I would like to make a dropdown list on my VF page that merely lists the contents of the picklist.

My VF page has

```
<apex:selectList value="{!category}" size="1" multiselect="false" styleClass="pickList" required="true">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!categoryList}"/>&nbsp;
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!saveCategoryValue}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

What is selected will be written to another custom object along with other items.  Currently, `saveCategoryValue` doesn't do anything.  I figured I needed to make the list show up before worrying about saving the selected value.

My controller has

```
public List<SelectOption> getcategoryList()
{ 
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult statusFieldCategory = Program__c.Categories__c.getDescribe(); // good
    List<Program__c> categories = [select id, Categories__c from Program__c];  // get the values from the Program__c object
    List<SelectOption> categoryList= new List<SelectOption> (); // create the list    
    for (Schema.Picklistentry picklistEntry : statusFieldCategory.getPicklistValues())
    {
    // put picklist values into an <apex:selectOptions> tag for VF display
    categoryList.add(new SelectOption(pickListEntry.getValue(),pickListEntry.getLabel()));
    }
    return categoryList;
}
```

When I preview the VF the drop down is empty.

At the top I have category declared as a string and I think somehow I need to put the selected value in category so that I can save it.  Before that I need to see the values.

I’m not understanding this, obviously.  What is wrong here?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I suspect that your code did not compile and save/deploy. Can you confirm that? Can you share more of the controller code? (ideally, the entire thing)

Comment: It does not produce any error messages.

Comment: I do not get any errors when I save.  Top of the controller has the following.  

Public with sharing class FRDSearchController {
// Application
    public FRDResourceApplication__c applicant;
    public String             category               {get;set;}   // Application dropdown value
    public String             selectedCatId          {set;get;}   // Application selected ID
    public FRDSearchController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.applicant=(FRDResourceApplication__c)controller.getRecord();
        selectedCatId ='';
    }

Comment: Then I tried a couple of things – 
    public List<SelectOption> getListOfCategory(){
        List<selectOption> options=new List<selectoption>();
        options.add(new selectOption('','--Select--'));
        for(Program__c cat:[select id, Categories__c from Program__c]){
            options.add(new selectOption(cat.id,cat.Categories__c));
        }
        return options; 
    }

Comment: And tried  -public List<SelectOption> getcategoryList()
{ 
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult statusFieldCategory = Program__c.Categories__c.getDescribe(); // good
    List<Program__c> categories = [select id, Categories__c from Program__c];  // get the values from the Program__c object
    List<SelectOption> categoryList= new List<SelectOption> (); // create the list
    for (Schema.Picklistentry picklistEntry : statusFieldCategory.getPicklistValues())
    {
    categoryList.add(new SelectOption(pickListEntry.getValue(),pickListEntry.getLabel()));
    }
    return categoryList;
}